# Лучший способ словить ивент DataGridViewComboBoxCell.SelectedItem Сhange

Tags: c#, datagridview

CellValueChanged() его не ловит.

А способа, которые я нашел, какие-то "хаковые". И большинство из них полно изьянов: например будут сыпатся ивенты, даже,если селектед итем не менялся, а просто был выделен сам DataGridViewComboBox.

А ведь должен же быть какой-то способ по-проще и элегантнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучший способ из найденных мной -- добавить CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged.

Даный способ форсит изменение валью при смене селектед итема, и, как следствие, CellValueChanged ловит событие ComboBoxCell.SelectedItemСhange.

```
private void DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var thisDatagridV = (DataGridView) sender;

     if (thisDatagridV.IsCurrentCellDirty)
     {
           thisDatagridV.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
     }
}
```